# std::tuple of two type VS. std::pair

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

Is there any advantage of using `std::pair` over `std::tuple` (or vice versa) when I need only two different types?

**For example:**

```
std::pair<int,double> foo;
std::tuple<int,double> bar;
```

I can name one advantage is that if I need, in future, to add a third type, `std::tuple` can serve me better than pair because I have to change the `std::pair` to `std::tuple` or to work around it (like making a `struct` that contains two of them).

By advantages, I mean performance, readability, usability, maintainability or anything...

**EDIT:**
I am seeking an answer that address performance, readability, usability, maintainability. All of these aspects were not addressed in the answers of that question which this question is marked as duplicated of it.

Comment: Performance depends on use case (if there is a difference) - you need to benchmark. The other three are subjective.

Comment: Well, the answers list all the differences. And (partly implicitly, partly explicitly) their possible impact on those acpects. Though how to assess and weigh them is partly subjective.